# How to get all columns of table1 and all rows of table2 which belong to table1?

Tags: mysql, sql

This are my tables/entities:

```
articles
- id
- title
- body

keywords
- id
- fk_article_id
- title
```

One article can have multiple keywords (one to many relationship, not many to many). There can be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ... keywords belonging to one article.

What's the best way to select the title and body for 1 article and titles of all it's keywords?

Result example:

```
- article.title
- article.body
-- keyword1.title
-- keyword2.title
-- keyword3.title
```

If i do an INNER JOIN, then i get the same article title and body twice. Can this be done with a GROUP BY or should i use NESTED statements?

The INNER JOIN which i tried, but is obviously not the right solution:

```
SELECT articles.title, articles.body, keywords.title
FROM articles
INNER JOIN keywords
ON articles.id = keywords.fk_article_id
WHERE articles.id = 1
```

Comment: Provide sample data, the result you are getting and the expected result.

Comment: Is it always three Keyword titles per article title ?

Comment: Provide sample data and the query you tried, and a psudo query that you want to achive. I helps a lazy helper like me answer the question.

Comment: Typically, you would have a table of articles, a table of keywords, and a table recording which keyword belongs to which article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sample suppose you have

```
articles
id   | title | body
----  -----   -----
1    | Harry Potter | text 
2    | LOTR | text text

keywords
id   | title 
----  -----   
1    |  magic
1    |  stick
2    | dwarf
2    | ring
```

If you execute the below query

```
Select a.title,a.body,group_concat(k.title ) from articles a JOIN keywords k ON a.id=k.id group by a.id
```

It will return
Harry Potter,(magic,stick)
LOTR,(dwarf,ring)

Comment: If this does not answer your question maybe you should rephrase your question.

Comment: How would the query look like without the group_concat()? Is that even possible? So that an array of keywords would be returned instead of a string?

Comment: @JoSmo : Without group_concat() query will pick the single field of each group & you can't directly get the array but in your server side script, you can convert comman separeted string to array very easily in php you have [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)